# POI workbookfactory read big Excel

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf, hssfworkbook

Is there a way to use WorkbookFactory with big Excel file? (5,5 MB)

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(file));
```

when the file became big, by using background-colors."
I get the error: `java.io.IOException: GC overhead limit exceeded.`
Altering the excel is not an option.
Is it possible to ignore the styles when reading the excel?
side info: The background was changed for a lot of rows that don't contain text.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/limitations.html) is the answer to your question:

**Writing**

> For writing very huge files, there is [SXSSFWorkbook](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/) which allows to do a streaming write of data out to files (with certain limitations
> on what you can do as only parts of the file are held in memory).

**Reading**

> For reading very huge files, take a look at the sample [XLSX2CSV](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java) which shows how you can read a file in streaming fashion (again with
> some limitations on what information you can read out of the file, but
> there are ways to get at most of it if necessary).